# Evaluating expectation $E(|X_1 + \cdots + X_n|^2)$

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Suppose I have scalar random variables $$X_1 + \cdots
 + X_n,$$ defined on some probability space and let $S_n$ be their sum.

How can I prove the identity $$\mathbb{E}|S_n|^2=\sum_i^n\sum_j^n\mathbb{E}X_i\overline{X_j} \quad
?$$

(I know  this question is relatively trivial, but it's been a long time since I've had to deal with probability/measure theory and so I got very rusty.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|S_n|^2=S_n\cdot\overline{S_n}=\sum_iX_i\cdot\sum_j\overline{X_j}=\sum_{i,j}X_i\overline{X_j}$$

Answer (score 0):

Is just the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) for $n=2$ ! (note that $|X|^2= X\bar{X}$).

Comment: Not really. More like the distributivity of the sums.

Comment: I guess the multinomial theorem is a bit of an overkill in this case ;).